# Nodejs mysql select response

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js

**How to Remove  double quotes from my output **

```
    app.get('/yearexpense',(req,res)=>{
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT login.display_name AS label, group_concat( daily_expenses.amount) AS data FROM login JOIN daily_expenses ON login.id = daily_expenses.user GROUP BY daily_expenses.user',(err,rows,fields)=>{
    if(!err)

        res.send(rows); 
})
```

});

**Expected Output**

```
[
  { data: [330, 600], label: 'Ravi' },
  { data: [120, 455], label: 'Amit' },
  { data: [45, 67], label: 'Roshan' }
];
```

**Getting Output**

```
[{"label":"Ravi Kanti","data":"[314,444]"},{"label":"Amit prakash","data":"[78]"},{"label":"Roshan Kumar","data":"[215,80,165]"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rows` variable inside of your `query()` callback contains the expected results.

W3Schools has some examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function passed as parameter to `mysqlConnection.query` is a callback. That means you cannot know when it will be executed.

you can use `async/await` syntax to make your call block until the query gives you a result.

You may need to use `util.promisify` on `mysqlConnection.query` to make it return a Promise.

Try this instead:

```
app.get('/yearexpense', async (req,res) => {
    try {
      const results = await mysqlConnection.query('SELECT login.display_name AS label, group_concat( daily_expenses.amount) AS data FROM login JOIN daily_expenses ON login.id = daily_expenses.user GROUP BY daily_expenses.user')
      // process the results
      // res.send(results)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
      // deal with the error
    }
})
```

Remember: to use the keyword `await` the surrounding function must be marked as `async`